# Which is the best way to do this using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find the number of rows in a column of Excel and minus one of the total rows. And assign this numeric value to variable.
Example:
Column A has data in 10 rows. 
Now using VBA script I should be able to find the total number of rows.
Total rows in column A is 10.
Then total minus 1.
10-1=9
And this 9 has to be assigned to a variable and shd be written in the excel sheet.
X is 9 .
The x value is 9 and it should get stored in column B as 009.

Suppose if X value is 38, it should get stored as 038 in column B

Please suggest the best possible way.

Comment: `Please suggest the best possible way.` - Try writing VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this website](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba) for finding the last row using VBA, then simply subtract `1` from your total row count

Check out [this website](http://www.excelhowto.com/macros/formatting-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-vba/) for formatting cells using VBA

FYI, this literally took me 10 seconds to Google these answers... you're welcome

Comment: @Sai, have a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920, where you'll find an interesting overview "Unreliable ways of finding last used cell". BTW, SO participation demands a question that summarizes the specific problem (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as a minimum of time invested by yourself instead of others (e.g. code examples so far).